# How to Access Shared Network Drive from Azure webjob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Getting access denied error when am trying to access shared network drive using UNC path from web job.
Am trying to read a file from shared folder and SFTP on client-server.
From local, it is working fine being able to access all files. But from azure web job getting access denied error to folder.
Here is my code :

```
 var con = new ConnectionInfo(host, 22, username, methods.ToArray());
                using (var client = new SftpClient(con))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to client");
                    client.Connect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to client");
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting file from Azure ");
                    string tstkey1 = File.ReadAllText(@"\\{shared folder}\test\test.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    string tstkey = File.ReadAllText(@"\\{shared folder}\test\test.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine(tstkey);                  
                    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tstkey);
                    Stream requestStream = new MemoryStream(fileContents);
                    Console.WriteLine(requestStream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploading to FILE to client SFTP");
                    client.UploadFile(requestStream, "/inbound/STEIN366_ACH_1/*.*" + "Test");
                    client.Disconnect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting File");
                    File.Delete(@"\\{folder}\test\test.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Dissconnected from client");
                }
```

Can someone help me, how to connect to the shared folder from Azure!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question title says *"shared network drive"*. Your code is for SFTP. So what are you really asking about? + Show us your exact exception error message and stacktrace.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl :  Here is my code from where am trying to read the file from a shared drive. 
                  
                    `string tstkey = File.ReadAllText(@"\\{Shared Drive}\test\test.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine(tstkey);                  
                    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tstkey);
                    Stream requestStream = new MemoryStream(fileContents);`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl :
**Error Message**:

**Error Message** :

`[ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\{Shared Folder}\test\test.txt' is denied.
[ ERR ]    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
[ ERR ]    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)`

Comment: **Edit your question** to 1) Show only the relevant code (no SFTP). 2) Show the exception details 3) Explain why you believe that the WebJob should be able to access the UNC path + Remove the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer files with SFTP you could use `WinSCP .NET Assembly`.

Here is the [guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_webjob_sftp) to use `WinSCP`. And you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364882/10383250) about `WinSCP` use.

If you still have questions, please let me know.